# I want to push either a TSV file or JSON up to a Google Sheet

Tags: ubuntu, csv, curl, google-spreadsheets, json

I have several large files of key/value pairs delimited by an equal sign ("="). One file is the master file. For each file, I want to populate columns A, B, and C as follows:

A: The unique key for each line in the master file
B: The value corresponding to the key in the master file.
C: The value corresponding to the same key in a secondary file.

I have no trouble converting all the files to either TSV or JSON, and I don't care which I use, because all I want to do is push it up to a Google Sheet and populate columns A, B, and C with the information described above.

I'm counting on being able to use CURL to push the data up to Google Sheets, but I'm new at this and don't know how to make it work (assuming it CAN be made to work). The goal is to have the Google Sheet for each master/secondary file pair be automatically populated as one step of a larger build job.

The sheets will be created (empty) and Published, in advance of the build, so that the URL of the Sheet can be made available to the build job.

The specific use is to supply text prompts for application forms in multiple languages. Column A is the key, B is the English, C is the target language. There will be a separate Sheet for each target language. This scheme is to facilitate translation efforts. We've been doing this for years, but always by hand. The goal is to automate the process.

Any and all advice and instruction will be gratefully received. Thank you.